# Render an animated object inside an irl video

Tags: animation

Is it possible to animate a single object inside a irl video. If so how could i achieve this.

Example: Animated bird landing onto a tree branch.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Yes. this happens all the time, it is called vfx, or visual effects. Lot of work, but something you can do 100% inside of blender.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a tutorial like "match track blend"

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g

and simpler from Blenderguru

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE

which is to comprehensive to be covered in a single answer.

As you seem to be fairly new, I suggest you look through the list

[Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)